# Uploading photos from Facebook to my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, paperclip

I am using rails3. Is it possible to upload photos from Facebook to my Rails app? Does anyone know of a way to do this.

Please provide me with an example if possible. Thanks.